# replace expression format xx-xx-xxxx_12345678

Tags: replace, ssis

| IDENTIFIER |
| --- |
| 31-03-2022_13636075 |
| 01-04-2022_13650262 |
| 04-04-2022_13663174 |
| 05-04-2022_13672025 |
| 20220099001 |
| 11614491_R |
| 10781198 |
| 00000000000 |
| 11283627_P |
| 11614491_R |
| -1 |

how can i remove (only) the "XX-XX-XXXXX_" Part in certain values of a column in SSIS but WITHOUT affecting values that doesn't have this format? For example "21-05-2022_12345678" = "12345678" but the other values i don't want them affected.  This are just examples of many rows from this column so i want only the ones that have this format to be affected.

```
SELECT REVERSE(substring(REVERSE('09-03-2022_13481330'),0,CHARINDEX('_',REVERSE('09-03-2022_13481330'),0)))
```

| result |
| --- |
| 13481330 |

but this also affects others values.Also this is in ssms not ssis because i am not sure how to transform this expression in ssis code.

Update : Corrected code in SSIS goes as following:

```
(FINDSTRING(IDENTIFIER,"__-__-____[_]",1) == 1) ? SUBSTRING(IIDENTIFIER,12,LEN(IDENTIFIER) - 11) : IDENTIFIER
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have access to the SQL source? You can do this on the sql by using a `LIKE` and crafting a match pattern using the single char wildcard `_` please see below example

```
DECLARE @Value VARCHAR(50) = '09-03-2022_13481330'
SELECT CASE WHEN @Value LIKE '__-__-____[_]%' THEN 
SUBSTRING(@Value,12,LEN(@Value)-11) ELSE @Value END
```

Please see the Microsoft Documentation on [LIKE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/like-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16#arguments:%7E:text=the%20book%20title.-,_%20(underscore),-Any%20single%20character) and using single char wildcards

If you don't have access to the source SQL it gets a bit more tricky as you might need to use regex in a script task or maybe there is a expression you can apply

Comment: thank you! i updated the original post with that converted code to SSIS. your expression works as it should be.